# Converting multiple data.table columns to factors in R

Tags: r, data.table

I ran into an unexpected problem when trying to convert multiple columns of a data table into factor columns.  I've reproduced it as follows:

```
library(data.table)
tst <- data.table('a' = c('b','b','c','c'))
class(tst[,a])
tst[,as.factor(a)]  #Returns expected result
tst[,as.factor('a'),with=FALSE] #Returns error
```

The latter command returns 'Error in Math.factor(j) : abs not meaningful for factors'.  I found this when attempting to get tst[,lapply(cols, as.factor),with=FALSE] where cols was a collection of rows I was attempting to convert to factors.  Is there any solution or workaround for this?

Comment: +1 I've added: [Gracefully catch internal abs() error on j when with=FALSE but j is wrongly factor](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=4867&group_id=240&atid=978)

Answer (score 36):

I found one solution:

```
library(data.table)
tst <- data.table('a' = c('b','b','c','c'))
class(tst[,a])
cols <- 'a'
tst[,(cols):=lapply(.SD, as.factor),.SDcols=cols]
```

Still, the earlier-mentioned behavior seems buggy.

Comment: You were trying to index the data.table with a factor - factors are neither characters nor numerics (they are categorical values with no clear magnitude), so data.table spits an error.

Comment: Also `tst[,as.factor(a)]` is just returning `as.factor(tst$a)` and is not indexing the data.table at all. Try `tst[,1:5]` to see what I mean.

Comment: you can try `tst[, a := as.factor(a)]` if you've just one column or do what you've shown or also use `set` within a for-loop over each of the columns.

Comment: Your error is because, you use `with=FALSE` and there are only a few possibilities for `j`. And `data.table` figures it out by checking if `j` is *logical* or *character* etc... and then comes to checking if they are column numbers.. and therefore checks `if (abs(j) > ncol(.))` where `j` is `factor(a)`. Here you call `abs` on a factor...

Comment: I was originally trying to change the type of multiple columns quickly with `cols:=as.factor(cols)`.  Is Arun's suggestion of set within a for loop preferred/faster?

Comment: @tresbot, have a look at ?set

Answer (score 4):

This is now fixed in [**v1.8.11**](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=240), but *probably not in the way you'd hoped for*. From [**NEWS**](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=datatable&revision=1025):

> FR #4867 is now implemented. `DT[, as.factor('x'), with=FALSE]` where `x` is a column in `DT`, is now equivalent to `DT[, "x", with=FALSE]` instead of ending up with an error. Thanks to tresbot for reporting on SO: [Converting multiple data.table columns to factors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525976/converting-multiple-data-table-columns-to-factors-in-r)

---

**Some explanation:** The difference, when `with=FALSE` is used, is that the columns of the `data.table` aren't seen  as variables anymore. That is:

```
tst[, as.factor(a), with=FALSE] # would give "a" not found!
```

would result in an error `"a" not found`. But what you do instead is:

```
tst[, as.factor('a'), with=FALSE]
```

You're in fact creating a factor `"a"` with `level="a"` and asking to *subset that column*. This doesn't really make much sense. Take the case of `data.frame`s:

```
DF <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=6:10)
DF[, c("x", "y")] # gives back DF

DF[, factor(c("x", "y"))] # gives back DF again, not factor columns
DF[, factor(c("x", "x"))] # gives back two columns of "x", still integer, not factor!
```

So, basically, what you're applying a factor on, when you use `with=FALSE` is *not* on the elements of that column, but just that column name... I hope I've managed to convey the difference well. Feel free to edit/comment if there are any confusions.