# Running `ctree` using `party` package, column as factor and not character

Tags: r, class, dataframe, classification, multiple-columns

I have referred [convert data.frame column format from character to factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251326/convert-data-frame-column-format-from-character-to-factor) and [Converting multiple data.table columns to factors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525976/converting-multiple-data-table-columns-to-factors-in-r) and [Convert column classes in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813578/convert-column-classes-in-data-table)

Unfortunately it did not solve my problem. I am working with the bodyfat dataset and my dataframe is called > bf. I added a column called agegrp to categorize persons of different ages as young, middle or old thus :

```
bf$agegrp<-ifelse(bf$age<=40, "young", ifelse(bf$age>40 & bf$age<55,"middle", "old"))
```

This is the ctree analysis:

```
> set.seed(1234)
> modelsample<-sample(2, nrow(bf), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7, 0.3))
> traindata<-bf[modelsample==1, ]
> testdata<-bf[modelsample==2, ]
> predictor<-agegrp~DEXfat+waistcirc+hipcirc+kneebreadth` and ran, `bf_ctree<-ctree(predictor, data=traindata)
> bf_ctree<-ctree(predictor, data=traindata)
```

I got the following error:

```
Error in trafo(data = data, numeric_trafo = numeric_trafo, factor_trafo = factor_trafo,  : 
  data class character is not supported
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(RET@predict_trafo) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Since `bf$agegrp` is of class "character" I ran,

```
> bf$agegrp<-as.factor(bf$agegrp)
```

the agegrp column is now coerced to factor.

`> Class (bf$agegrp)` gives `[1] "Factor"`.

I tried running the `ctree` again, but it throws the same error. Does anyone know what the root-cause of the problem is?

Comment: Try `br$agegrp <- as.factor(bf$agegrp)`.

Comment: that will create a new variable. How Will I use it in my existing bf dataframe to run the c-tree?

Comment: @jlhoward `bf$agegrp<-as.factor(bf$agegrp)` returns bf$agegrp as factor but my ctree is returning the same error!

Comment: Sorry, typo:  I meant `bf$agegrp <- as.factor(bf@agegrp)`

Comment: Gonna try taking the whole thing from the top!

Comment: I don't quite follow. You're passing traindata to ctree, but you're making changes in bf...?

Comment: @joran I created two partitions of the dataframe as traindata and testdata using this: `set.seed(1234)`, `modelsample<-sample(2, nrow(bf), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7, 0.3))`, `traindata<-bf[modelsample==1, ]` and `testdata<-bf[modelsample==2, ]` , I'll add that to my question.

Comment: How is `traindata` defined? If I run `bf_ctree<-ctree(predictor, data=bf)`, I don't get an error.

Comment: @jlhoward I just updated it in the question, all the commands in the ctree analysis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
library(mboot)
library(party)
bf <- bodyfat
bf$agegrp <- cut(bf$age,c(0,40,55,100),labels=c("young","middle","old"))
predictor <- agegrp~DEXfat+waistcirc+hipcirc+kneebreadth

set.seed(1234)
modelsample <-sample(2, nrow(bf), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7, 0.3))
traindata   <-bf[modelsample==1, ]
testdata    <-bf[modelsample==2, ]
bf_ctree    <-ctree(predictor, data=traindata)
plot(bf_ctree)
```

[image]

Comment: bang on! the problem seemed to be in the way I added the variable `$agegrp` with `ifelse`. Any idea why that may have been causing problem?

Comment: Not really. The factor levels are in a different order with `as.factor(ifelse(...ifelse(...)))`. Perhaps that has something to do with it.